# Is it better to create a OneToOne relation or a custom filed?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a Venue model and save the location object, here's my code that actually works:

```
class Location(models.Model): 
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location)
```

As you can see, if I delete Venue the corresponding location will not be deleted, because OneToOne works so.
Is it better to create a custom field, let's say `LocationField`, with `latitude`, `longitude`... properties and put it inside `Venue`, or is this the right solution?

**UPDATE:**

```
class Location(models.Model): 
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)        
    venue = models.OneToOneField(Venue)
        
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Depends on your logic. If a location can optionally be a Venue, then its ok. If you need you need all fields all the time, then everything in one model would be best.

Comment: So, based on your answer, I updated the question, what do you think?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that. Again, it depends on your logic. Maybe this will help you as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/